# A condition that implies commutativity

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring. A notable theorem of **N. Jacobson** states that if the identity $x^{n}=x$ holds for every $x \in R$ and a fixed $n \geq 2$ then $R$ is a commutative ring.

The proof of the result for the cases $n=2, 3,4$ is the subject matter of several  well-known exercises in **Herstein**'s *Topics in Algebra*. The corresponding proofs rely heavily on "elementary" manipulations. For instance, the proof of the case $n=3$ can be done as follows:

1) If $a, b \in R$ are such that $ab= 0$ then $ba=0$.

2) $a^{2}$ and $-a^{2}$ belong to $\mathbf{Z}(R)$ for every $a \in R$.

3) Since $(a^{2}+a)^{3} = (a^{2}+a)^{2}+(a^{2}+a)^{2}$ it follows that

$a=a+a^{2}-a^{2} = (a+a^{2})^{3}-a^{2} = (a^{2}+a)^{2}+(a^{2}+a)^{2}-a^{2}$

and whence the result. ▮

Certainly, the mind can't but boggle at the succinctness of the above solution. Actually, it is the conciseness of this argument that has prompted me to pose the present question: **is an analogous demonstration of the general theorem possible?** The one that appears in [**1**] depends on some non-trivial structure theorems for division rings.

As usual, I thank you in advance for your insightful replies, reading suggestions, web links, etc...

**References**

[**1**] I. N. Herstein, *Noncommutative rings*, The Carus Mathematical Monographs, no. 15, Mathematical Association of America, 1968.

[**2**] I. N. Herstein, Álgebra Moderna, Ed. Trillas, págs. 112, 119, and 153.

Comment: As a commutative reader, I'd like to learn what are your (2) and (3) above. What is **Z**$(R)$? Why $(a^2+a)^3=(a^2+a)^2+(a^2+a)^2$?

Comment: My guess is that Z(R) is the center of the ring and 3) follows from a^3=a, I think.

Comment: I have a similar guess for (3) but this isn't as obvious as what follows in (3). That's why I ask the author or everybody who loves this question (and it's obviously liked!) to give some details. Thanks!

Comment: I just wanted to mention that there is a relevant article by Kaplansky, *Commutativity Revisited*.  It appears (only) in his **Selected Papers and Other Writings**.  The beginning of it is available on google books.  

Comment: I forgot to mention that Jacobson actually proved a stronger result (and Kaplansky's paper discusses for the most part yet stronger results): the conclusion still holds if the exponent $n \geq 2$ is allowed to depend on $x$.  

Comment: The standard notation for the centre of the ring $R$ is $Z(R)$
(the $Z$ not usually bold).

My idle speculation is that there should be a "calculational"
proof like the given one for any particular $n$, but there being
such a proof
for all $n$ seems unlikely. Treating general $n$ I suspect
needs "second-order" concepts: subrings, ideals, quotients, stuff
like that.

Comment: 1. $\mathbf{Z}(R)$ is the center of the ring. 2. I don't see what the problem with #3 is: $(a^2+a)^3=(a^2+a)^2(a^2+a)=(a^2+a+a^2+a)(a^2+a).$ 3. Indeed, there are several stronger results (cf. chapter 3 of Herstein's Noncommutative rings). Yitz expressed therein that the version mentioned by Pete, "as proved has one drawback; true enough, it implies commutativity but only very few commutative rings exist which satisfy its hypothesis."

Comment: I don't think this paper gives quite the succint argument you want, but it may be an improvement over previous proofs: 
http://www.springerlink.com/content/p760r6271707j8q7/

Comment: @Wadim: My (1), (2), and (3) above are proof steps. 

Comment: Great, I now follow your problem. Thanks!

Comment: The first page of the Jacobson article mentioned by in one of Kap's short pieces, mentioned in turn by Pete, is at link    
http://www.jstor.org/pss/1969205   
The second paragraph contains the result with varying exponent. 
 


Comment: $\textit{Certainly, the mind can't but boggle at the succinctness of the above solution}$ Indeed, I don't understand it at all, especially "whence the result" (step 3 involves only one ring element, whereas two are needed for commutativity). Have you not made it a bit $\textit{too}$ succint?

Comment: @Viktor- 3) gives any element 'a' as the sum/difference of squares of elements and from 2) (and the closure of the centre under addition) we have that 'a' belongs to the centre.

Comment: Thank you, Tom! That also explains why both $a^2$ and $-a^2$ were mentioned in 2 :) I find it amusing that the author expects us to see that the "identity" $\implies 1$ and $1 \implies 2$ right away, but worries that we may get lost with "center is closed under negation".

Comment: It's not that I worry about that. I was just mentioning what the ingredients of the proof are...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

For fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$, Birkhoff's completeness theorem implies that such a proof must exist in the first-order equational theory of rings - as I mentioned here in a recent [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30220/abstract-thought-vs-calculation/30273#30273). Many years ago Stan Burris told me that John Lawrence discovered such an equational proof that works uniformly for all $n$ (possibly also for Jacobson's form $x^{n(x)} = x$). I don't know if the proof is published yet, but some clues as to how it may proceed might be gleaned from their earlier joint [work [1]] [1](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Esnburris/htdocs/MYWORKS/PAPERS/fields3.pdf)

[1](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Esnburris/htdocs/MYWORKS/PAPERS/fields3.pdf) S. Burris and J. Lawrence, Term rewrite rules for finite fields.
International J. Algebra and Computation 1 (1991), 353-369.
[http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~snburris/htdocs/MYWORKS/PAPERS/fields3.pdf](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Esnburris/htdocs/MYWORKS/PAPERS/fields3.pdf)

Comment: Has there been any development on this subject in these years? Is the proof published now? (I can't find it)

Comment: Based on my work, I highly doubt that there is an equational proof that works uniformly in $n$. Nevertheles, I am also very interested in John Lawrence's proof. The linked paper is not very helpful for the problem here.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, it is possible to write down an equational proof for every $n$. This is covered in the preprint

> [Equational proofs of Jacobson's Theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.05301), arXiv:2310.05301 [math.RA]

The rough idea is to prove the reduction to prime characteristic $p$ and then to $n=p^k$ in a constructive way. Then, the (more or less equivalent) proofs by Dolan and Nagahara-Tominaga, which reduce the Theorem to Wedderburn's Theorem, can be made constructive as well. The paper discusses several examples. For example, every ring with $x^{2023}=x$ is commutative by an equational proof.

I have started this project in 2014, then continued in 2020, and now finished it (finally!) in 2023. Unfortunately, there are still some cases missing. Namely, if $\mathrm{gcd}(k,p^k-1) > 1$ (cf. [MO/455808](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/455808/when-is-mathrmgcdk-pk-1-1-true)), the constructive Wedderburn Theorems $W_{p,k,T^m}$ from the paper (which are used to prove that $p^k$-rings of characteristic $p$ are commutative) can only be verified *theoretically* by a computer program.

The issue with using Birkhoff's Completeness Theorem (as mentioned in Bill's answer) is that it is a pure existence result (see [MO/353564](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/353564)). It does not tell us how equational proofs look like.

Comment: Cool! I am going to take at look at your preprint later on...