# On a theorem of Jacobson

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, ac.commutative-algebra

In a comment to an [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30220/abstract-thought-vs-calculation/30273#30273) to a MO question, in which Bill Dubuque mentioned Jacobson's theorem stating that a ring in which $X^n=X$ is an identity is commutative (theorem which has shown up on MO quite a bit recently, e.g. [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29590/a-condition-that-implies-commutativity)), Pierre-Yves Gaillard observed that there is a more general theorem in which $n$ is allowed to be different for each element of the ring, 
so that in fact we can rephrase the theorem as saying that the set $S=\{X^n-X:n>1\}\subset\mathbb Z[X]$ has the following property:

> If $A$ is a ring such that for every $a\in A$ there is an $f\in S$ such that $f(a)=0$, then $A$ is commutative.

Of course, $S\cup (-S)$ also has this property, and even if we construct $S'$ from $S\cup(-S)$ by closing it under the operation of taking divisors in $\mathbb Z[X]$, it also has the same property. Pierre-Yves then asked:

> Is $S'$ maximal for this property?

So, is it?

Comment: Of course, one can very easily become greedy and start asking questions like «can one classify sets with that property?» and so on. This looked like a good start :)

Comment: Any set containing S seems to work.  Perhaps you should edit the question so it asks the classification question in you comment.  (E.g. classify minimal sets S with this property).  Note that S is not minimal either; consider $X^{n!}-X$ for example.

Comment: If S works then a subset of S also work. Maximal is the right question. 

Comment: @Litt, I guess you are taking minimal in cardinality. But minimal in what sense, such that it implies commutative? x^2-x=0 is enough. 
Notice that putting more elements in the set doesn't necessarily make things better to get the commutativity because then some a's can satisfy equations from S and some others satisfy the new equations. (or all satisfy the new equations).

Comment: Dear Mariano: Thanks for mentioning this question. I think one should ask if $S\cup(-S)$ [and not $S$] is maximal for the property in question. 

Comment: Ah I see, you're right of course.

Comment: and x-1 can be also added to S

Comment: $S$ isn't remotely maximal, as far as I can see. For example any divisor of $X^n-X$ for any $n$ can be added to it, as if $P(X)=0$ for $P$ some divisor of $X^n-X$ then $X^n-X=0$. Moreover, if you have a ring in which every element other than the number 9 satisfies $X^n=X$ for some $n$, then 9 will also satisfy this, because $3^n=3$ implies $9^n=9$. So you can also add $X-9$ to $S$. And so on and so on...

Comment: [clarification: "divisor" means "divisor in $\mathbf{Z}[X]$"]

Comment: Let's add to $S\cup-S$ the degree one monic polynomials, 
the divisors of the $X^n-X$, and the negatives of the 
above. Is this enlarged set maximal? 

Comment: @Pierre: can you prove that your set _works_ before we start worrying about whether it's maximal? I only added $X-9$, I didn't add all $X-n$ *simultaneously*. But my gut instinct is that, if your set is OK, it won't be maximal because there are still plenty of other stupid tricks you can try (square of a linear factor etc). Note however that if someone comes up with an enlargement and then someone else says "OK then is this enlarged set maximal" we could be here all year!

Comment: Dear Kevin, I think my set works because the prime ring 
is always central. 

Comment: @Pierre: that, for me, is not a proof. The theorem, as I understand it, is that if for all $r$ there's $n$ with $r^n=r$ then $R$ is commutative. But this $r^n=r$ thing is a _huge_ extra constraint on the ring, that most commutative rings do not come close to satisfying. It shows, for example, that the ring has finite characteristic (set $r=2$). If you remove this trick (because $r=2$ is no longer allowed) can you still prove that $R$ is commutative? You know more about the proof than I do, I'm sure, but I don't think your comment is enough---it's certainly not enough for me, at least!

Comment: Dear Kevin: I fully agree with you! My previous two 
comments were completely silly! Sorry about that ...

Comment: It still might be true though! I certainly don't know a counterexample (as you probably guessed---because if I did I would have played it instantly!). I am not optimistic about finding a "nice" maximal set though. I think the first thing to do is to read the proof and to see what's really going on, and to go from there.

Answer (score 6):

Herstein proved that $S$ can be enlarged to the set of all $a^2 p(a) - a$ with $p$ a polynomial (with integer coefficients).

EDIT.  Herstein's set may be maximal.  The set can't contain any polynomials whose vanishing would be consistent with the ring containing (nonzero) nilpotent elements, so nothing in $S$ can be divisible by $a^2$. The lower degree terms are also highly constrained by the condition that if there is $p$-torsion then no $p^2$-torsion.

Comment: I think I found the reference:
Herstein, I. N. The structure of a certain class of rings.
Amer. J. Math. 75, (1953). 864-871. ---
Herstein even proves this: If, for every $a$ a ring $R$, there 
exists a polynomial $p_a(t)$ (with integral coefficients) such 
that $a^2p_a(a)-a$ is central, then $R$ is commutative. 

Comment: Yes, I should have explained that the full result only requires central rather than zero, but the latter is enough to answer the question.  I never proved the full Jacobson theorem but I did work out the $f(x) = x^n - x$ problem some time ago (using the universal ring generated by the required relations) and if I remember correctly, the key conditions are that $f(x)=x$ mod $p$ and the form of $f$ rules out nilpotent elements.  These two conditions easily force a direct sum decomposition into finite fields and this concludes the proof.  Herstein apparently showed this is enough in general.

Comment: I hope the following is correct. Let $A$ be the set of $f(X)\in\mathbb Z[X]$ with constant term $\pm1$, let $XA$ be the set of 
the $Xf(X)$, $f(X)$ in $A$. Let $R$ be a ring and $C$ its center. Herstein's Theorem says that if for any $r$ in $R$ there is an $f(X)$ in $XA$ such that $f(r)$ is in $C$, then $R=C$. It implies trivially the following. Put $B:=\{X-n\ |\ n\in\mathbb Z\}$. If 
for any $r$ in $R$ there is an $f(X)$ in $XA\cup A$ such that $f(r)=0$, then $R=C$. If for any $r$ in $R$ there is an $f(X)$ in $XA\cup B$ such that $f(r)$ is in $C$, then $R=C$. 

Comment: @T.: Herstein's set isn't maximal because you can add $X-1$.

Comment: If you allow the zero ring as a ring, yes. But the $\pm X-n$ and the ones from A   in Pierre-Yves' comment seem to be all you can add to Herstein's set. – T.  2 mins ago

Comment: In my previous comment, one can replace 
$B:=\{X-n\ |\ n\in\mathbb Z\}$ with 
$B:=\{\pm X-n\ |\ n\in\mathbb Z\}$. 