# Birkhoff's completeness theorem put into practice

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, universal-algebra, proof-theory, constructive-mathematics

Birkhoff's completeness theorem (see [here](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~snburris/htdocs/ualg.html), Theorem 14.19) states that an equation which is true in all models of an algebraic theory can be proven in [equational logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equational_logic).

**Question.** Does the proof of Birkhoff's completeness theorem actually *produce* for each specific equation a proof in equational logic? If yes, can you please demonstrate this with an instructive example?

Actually, I suspect that the answer is "No", but I am not entirely sure.

Let us look at the following well-known statement: If $R$ is a ring in which every element $r \in R$ satisfies $r^2=r$ (i.e. $R$ is boolean), then $R$ is commutative. There is the following overkill proof: $R$ is reduced, [hence](https://ysharifi.wordpress.com/2010/06/04/about-reduced-rings-2/)  a subdirect product of domains $R_i$. Since the maps $R \to R_i$ are surjective, each domain $R_i$ satisfies the same equation and then must be isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_2$. In particular, $R_i$ is commutative. Since $R \to \prod_{i \in I} R_i$ is injective, it follows that $R$ is commutative. So by Birkhoff's theorem, there *must be some* equational proof of this. My question is not how an equational proof looks like - this is just a basic algebra exercise. I would like to see how (if possible) it can be extracted from the overkill proof.

I think the proof of Birkhoff's theorem in this special case works as follows: Consider the free ring on two generators $\mathbb{Z}\langle X,Y\rangle$ and take the quotient with respect to the relations $r^2=r$ for all elements $r$. This is the free boolean ring $R$ on two generators. By the overkill proof, $XY=YX$ holds in $R$. This means that $XY=YX$ can be derived from the relations $r^2=r$ in $\mathbb{Z}\langle X,Y\rangle$. But we don't *get* a derivation, right? How to produce, for example, the following equation?

$$\begin{align*}
XY - YX &= \bigl((X+Y)^2 - (X+Y)\bigr) - \bigl(X^2-X\bigr) - \bigl(Y^2-Y\bigr) \\
&\phantom{=}+ \bigl((YX)^2 - (YX)\bigr) - \bigl((-YX)^2 - (-YX)\bigr),
\end{align*}$$
As far as I can tell, we are not even guaranteed a priori to have a proof which works without the axiom of choice, since this is used in the structure theorem for reduced rings in the overkill proof? (At first this might be confusing since the axiom of choice is surely not allowed in an equational proof, but actually the axiom of choice is used to show the *existence* of an equational proof.)

I am interested in more complicated applications of Birkhoff's theorem.  This here is just an example to get started. You can also choose other examples if they are more instructive.

Comment: There should be varieties with nonrecursive (but r.e.) equational theories.  Short of doing computations in a finitely generated relatively free algebra, I am not sure how to answer your question when it can be answered at all.  Gerhard "Equational Proof Is Just Equations" Paseman, 2020.02.25.

Comment: It is an old theoren of Jacobson that if R if a ring satisfying the equation $x^n=x$ is commutative.  The prof uses subdirect products  and structure of division rings.  There are very few examples of $n$ where an equational proof of commutativity is known.  Birkhoff’s proof uses choice I believe and doesn’t really tell you how to get equations.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Actually, I have an equational proof for infinitely many $n$. :-)

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: I do not think there is a known variety of rings with undecidable equational theory. Ring varieties behave much better than group or semigroup varieties.

Comment: I am pretty sure that Alexei Kanel-Belov has a syntactic proof of Jacobson's theorem.

Comment: @MarkSapir Interesting. Could you please give a reference for the syntactic proof?

Comment: I was wrong. Alexei Kanel-Belov does not know a purely syntactic proof. Says that he would be interested to see such a proof for infinitely many $n$, What can be easily proved syntactocally. is that the Jacobson radical of such rings is trivial.

Comment: All right, thank you.

Comment: @MarkSapir, Jacobson's identity means the ring is von Neumann regular (in fact completely regular as a semigroup). This trivially forces the radical to be zero since every non-zero left ideal of a von Neumann regular ring has a nonzero idempotent and the radical cannot have a nonzero idempotent since they are not left quasiregular.

Comment: The radical of a PI ring is nilpotent (which has a completely syntactic proof) and $x^t=x$ imply that nilelements are 0.

Comment: Even easier, the Jacobson radical cannot contain non-trival idempotents and if $x^n=x$ then $x^{n-1}$ is an idempotent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let me try to restate the question.

I consider an identity to be a pair, written $(s,t)$ or $s\approx t$. I also consider a set of identities to be a set of pairs.

Birkhoff's Theorem compares three things, namely
(1) $\Sigma\models s\approx t$,
(2) The pair $(s,t)$ belongs to the fully invariant congruence $\Theta^{T(X)}(\Sigma)$ on the term algebra $T(X)$, and 
(3) $\Sigma\vdash s\approx t$.

I think the question is asking whether it is possible to extract *from the proof of Birkhoff's Theorem* and from a specific instance of $\Sigma\models s\approx t$ a proof witnessing that $\Sigma \vdash s\approx t$.

The proof of Birkhoff's theorem does explain why (1) $\Leftrightarrow$ (2). Also, if we are told HOW the pair $(s,t)$ is generated as a member of $\Theta^{T(X)}(\Sigma)$, that can be translated into a $\Sigma$-proof of $s\approx t$. What is missing is: given the knowledge that 
$(s,t)\in\Theta^{T(X)}(\Sigma)$, do we know how the pair $(s,t)$ got into $\Theta^{T(X)}(\Sigma)$?
The proof of Birkhoff's Theorem does not require this missing ingredient, it only requires that if $(s,t)$ is in $\Theta^{T(X)}(\Sigma)$, then it was generated in some way. So the answer to the question in the form it was asked (can we extract a $\Sigma$-proof of $s\approx t$ *from the proof of Birkhoff's Theorem*?) has to be No.

You could try asking a slightly different question: Suppose, given *finite* $\Sigma$, that we are told that $\Sigma \models s\approx t$. By B's Theorem we know there must exist a $\Sigma$-proof of $s\approx t$. Question: can we estimate an upper bound on the complexity of such a proof?

An affirmative answer would imply that any finitely axiomatizable variety has a decidable equational theory. But we know this to be false, since in the 1940's Tarski found a finitely axiomatizable variety of relation algebras with an undecidable equational theory. Many other examples are known now.

Comment: Thank you! So my guess was correct.

Answer (score 1):

The proof of Birkhoff's theorem, much like the proof of the completeness theorem for predicate logic, will not give a very interesting algorithm for computing a proof for a statement known to be valid: it will essentially consist of a naive proof search which, for a valid statement, will terminate. But as Keith Kearnes wrote, there cannot be a computable bound for the size of a proof in the size of the statement.

However, note that Birkhoff's theorem uses only the **truth** of the statement under consideration. It does not use any information contained in any of the known **proofs** of the statement. In proof theory there are techniques for using this information, in particular Gentzen's cut-elimination theorem. It provides a proof transformation which, in some sense, allows to remove notions for a proof which do not appear in the theorem it shows. Famous applications of the cut-elimination theorem to mathematical proofs are Girard's transformation of the Fürstenberg-Weiss proof of van der Waerden's theorem into the original proof [1, annex 4.A] and Luckhardt analysis of Roth's theorem about approximations of irrational numbers [2].
A strongly related line of work is proof mining [3] which focuses on the extraction of functionals and bounds from proofs.

Instead of applying Birkhoff's theorem, it may be more fruitful to apply such proof-theoretic techniques since they also allow to leverage the proof of the statement under consideration.

[1] J.Y. Girard: Proof Theory and Logical Complexity. In Studies in Proof
Theory, Bibliopolis, Napoli, 1987.

[2] Horst Luckhardt. Herbrand-Analysen zweier Beweise des Satzes von
Roth: Polynomiale Anzahlschranken. Journal of Symbolic Logic,
54(1):234–263, 1989.

[3] Ulrich Kohlenbach. Applied Proof Theory: Proof Interpretations and
their Use in Mathematics. Springer, 2008.