# When is $\mathrm{gcd}(k,p^k-1)=1$ true?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, integer-sequences

Let $p$ be a prime. Is there a classification of the numbers $k \geq 1$ such that $\gcd(k,p^k-1)=1$? If not, can we at least produce an explicit infinite subset? What is known about these $k$?

For the lack of a better name, let me call **$k$ good for $p$** if $\gcd(k,p^k-1)=1$. Many numbers are good for $p=2$. This seems to be related but not identical to the OEIS sequence [A049093](https://oeis.org/A049093). If $p>2$, all good numbers for $p$ are odd. Most odd numbers are good for $3$; for $k \leq 1000$ the only $24$ exceptions are `39, 55, 117, 165, 195, 253, 273, 275, 351, 385, 429, 495, 507, 585, 605, 663, 715, 741, 759, 819, 825, 897, 935, 975`. There is no OEIS sequence for these. For $p=5$ it is similar, but for $p > 5$ the story becomes different.

*Background.* I have found an equational proof that $p^k$-rings with $p=0$ are commutative when $\gcd(k,p^k-1)=1$ (see [Equational proofs of Jacobson's Theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.05301)). Now, I wonder how many cases I have already covered.

Comment: It would be nicer if your name "good" actually involved the prime $p$, e.g., "$p$-good".

Comment: @KConrad done !

Comment: "... if this question turns out to be stupid." -- actually, the question is fine, and only the final words about "... stupid" were not smart (I've up-voted this Q. anyway :-) ).

Comment: @WlodAA removed!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is easier to describe non-good (*bad*) numbers with respect to a given prime $p$. For each such number $k$, there exists a prime $q$ such that $q\mid k$ and $q\mid (p^k - 1)$. It follows that $k$ is multiple of $m_p(q):=q\cdot \mathrm{ord}_q(p)$, where $\mathrm{ord}_q(p)$ is the multiplicative order of $p$ modulo $q$ (which is a divisor of $q-1$). Hence, the set of bad $k$ is formed by the union
$$\bigcup_{q\in\mathbb{P}\atop q\ne p} m_p(q) \mathbb{N}^+.$$

**UPDATE#2.** It also follows that

- for any odd $k$, there exists a prime $p$ such that $k$ is good for $p$;
- any even $k$ is bad for all primes $p\geq 3$ since $2\mid
     \gcd(k,p^k-1)$;

Comment: A nice answer. ###### 

BTW, instead of p-*non-good* name, more logical and much nicer would be name p-*bad*.

Comment: Very nice! What can we then say about the density of the bad numbers?

Comment: @WlodAA: I've changed non-good to bad per popular request :)

Comment: Max, great, wonderful! ########## Mathematicians and others should be trained in poetry though at the same time they should ignore a great majority of poets and literary critics.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev what are uniformly bad numbers? You mean for all p?

Comment: Regarding the update: when $k$ is bad for all primes, why is $k$ divisible by $q(q-1)$ for some odd prime $q$? I was assuming that it follows from the first result since "generically" some prime $p$ will generate $(\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$, but this argument is not precise at all. I cannot make it work. Where should the $q$ come from?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Let $k$ be not divisible by any $q(q-1)$. Then, for any prime divisor $q|k$ consider a primitive root $r_q$ modulo $q$, and combine them by CRT into some $r$ modulo $\mathrm{rad}(k)$. By Dirichlet theorem, there is a prime $p\equiv r\pmod{\mathrm{rad}(k)}$. It's easy to check that $k$ is good for $p$.

Comment: I don't understand the final density calculation. If you have a union of arithmetic progressions containing $0$ with pairwise coprime common differences $d_1, \dots, d_k$ then it is true that their union has density $(1-1/d_1) \cdots (1-1/d_k)$, by CRT. The converse is true too: if the union has density given by the product then $d_1, \dots, d_k$ are pairwise coprime, and the integers $q(q-1)$ are not pairwise coprime!

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Thanks! (So my intuition for the proof was correct, after all.) I would write the proof without the pseudo-contradiction. But I have troubles with the prime $2$. Assume that $k$ is bad for all primes. Construct $p$ as in your comment. Then $k$ is bad for $p$, so there is a prime $q \mid k$ with $q \mid p^k - 1$. Then one can show indeed $q-1 \mid k$. So we are done if $q > 2$. But what do we do when $q = 2$?

Comment: Apart from the problem with the case $q=2$, this arguement shows the existence of primes $p_k$ such that $k$ is bad for all primes iff $k$ is bad for $p_k$, right?

Comment: @SeanEberhard: Good point, thanks! I messed up what I thought is a bound with an exact value. The latter can be computed with inclusion-exclusion, but it turns out not relevant anymore (see update#2).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Yes, prime $2$ "destroys" the nice picture. I was keeping it out of play, and my update#1 was wrong in that respect. Please see update#2.